# Matlab/octave passing callback reference to GUI initialization function

Tags: user-interface, callback, octave

I am learning to write a GUI application in Octave. Having a code with couple GUI controls (e.g. buttons) and attached callback function that is saved as a standalone function in separate file (function `hp53132_update_param_callback(obj)`).

When I use the callback function reference in the GUI elements placed straight in the main M-code script, the function is called properly.
In the next step I wanted to wrap the GUI element objects into a wrapper function that would be called upon initialization of the GUI.
For that purpose I wrote a function `hp53132_gui_initialize(hfig, callback_function)` with a snippet of the code below.

```matlab
function h = hp53132_gui_initialize(hfig, callback_function)

h.panel1 = uipanel('Parent',hfig, 'Units','normal','Position', [2/3 0 1/3 1]);
 h.ch1_zin_radio_buttons = uibuttongroup('Parent',h.panel1, 'Position', [0 0.85 1/5 0.1]);
  h.ch1_zin_radio_Z_50Ohm = uicontrol ...
                                   ("Parent",h.ch1_zin_radio_buttons, "style", "radiobutton",
                                   "units", "normalized",
                                   "string", "50Ohm",
                                   "callback", @callback_function,
                                   "value", 0,
                                   "position", [0.1 0.4 0.9 0.2]); 
 % and so forth...
endfunction
```

However, when I try to pass the function reference as an argument to it in the main script as

```matlab
hfig = figure('Units', 'normal', 'Position', [0.1 0.1 .8 .9]);  %not quite full screen

h=hp53132_gui_initialize(hfig,@hp53132_update_param_callback);

guidata(hfig,h); % set GUI custom data, pass it to gcf object for callback functions
```

I get a following error message when I push a button or change some GUI control.

```
callback_function = @hp53132_update_param_callback
>> error: invalid function handle, unable to find function for @callback_function
error: invalid function handle, unable to find function for @callback_function
```

It seems that the callback function reference gets lost somewhere. I tried to define it as persistent, but this did not help.

Answer (score 0):

This seems more like an issue with your MatLab/Octave environment.

Running your code does not produce any errors (1 Warning on the use of '`normal`' rather than '`normalize`' for your units) but no error.

I would double check that you have included the location of your function on the path, and if not add it to the path either programmatically (see the function `addpath`) or manually using the file browser.